# Change an image with a new uploaded one and make it persistent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my html page, I have an image. I would like that when I click on the image I open the file uploader and select a new image (I don't want to show the file upload button).
Then, I need that the uploaded image replaces the already existing one.
Finally, I would like that the result stays persistent. I mean when I refresh the page I would like to keep the new uploaded image.

Comment: your question can be answered multiple ways and there doesn't seem any snippets provided. what have you tried? where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need to create the variable that would store the path to the picture and whenever you change the image, your logic overwrites the path.
Hope it helps!